# Matlab equivalent for R's "qlogis"?

Tags: r, matlab

I am transcribing some R code for MATLAB.

```
L = qlogis(p)
```

I looked it up, and it's the "quantile of the logistic distribution" corresponding to a probability. Does anyone know how I can do this in Matlab? I have been looking at the help for `icdf` as I thought that might be similar, but can't find `logistic` in it.

I have the statistics toolbox.

Comment: There's no logit function?

Comment: Downvote because it was so easy to find the answer by googling.

Comment: Is "logit" the same as "logistic"? Sorry, I didn't realise that! But no,  I can't find a preexisting logistic function.

Comment: Oh, is that all it is? `log(p/(1-p))`? I assumed it would be something more complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## R2012a

From the documentation on my local install of this version, there is no built-in support for the Logistic distribution by the statistics toolbox.
However, not being a hardcore statistician and having to trust Wikipedia, you can make a quick inline function for the quantile:

```
qlogis = @(p,mu,sigma) mu + sigma * log(p./(1-p));
```

## R2013a+

From this version onward, you simply pass the name of a supported distribution to `icdf` as an argument:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = 1;
q = icdf('logistic',mu,sigma);
```

[Current documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/icdf.html).